# Null pointer exception from Service when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a Broadcast reciever which invokes service based on the pendingIntent. The service is working fine when activity is onPause state, but when the app's onDestroy is called, service is giving NullPointer.

BaseActivity---

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isResume = false;
    isPutToBackground = true;
    isDataPutToBackground = true;
    setNotification(_instance, false);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (!isResume) {
        isResume = false;
        isPutToBackground = true;
        isDataPutToBackground = true;
        setNotification(_instance, true);
    }}

    public static void setNotification(Context ctx, boolean isDestroyed) {
    cancelNotification(_instance);
    myIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);
    dataIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);

    if (!Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn) {
        createDailyReminder(ctx, false, false, isDestroyed);
    } else {
        if (Prefs.getInstance().isDataReminder) {
            createWeeklyReminder(ctx, isDestroyed);

        }
        if (Prefs.getInstance().reminderInterval.equals("1 Day")|| Prefs.getInstance().reminderInterval.equals("")) {
            createDailyReminder(ctx, true, false, isDestroyed);
        } else {
            createDailyReminder(ctx, true, true, isDestroyed);
        }
    }

}

public static void cancelNotification(Context ctx) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);
Intent dataIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 11122, myIntent, 0);
dataPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 11133, dataIntent,0);
dataPendingIntent.cancel();
pendingIntent.cancel();
alreadyBackrogund = false;
dataAlreadyBackrogund = false;
}

private static void createWeeklyReminder(Context ctx, boolean isDestroyed) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
dataIntent.putExtra("DATA", true);
if (isDestroyed) {
dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", true);
} else {
dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", false);
}
dataPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 11122, dataIntent,0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, dataPendingIntent);

}

private static void createDailyReminder(Context ctx, boolean loggedIn,
        boolean isWeekly, boolean isDestroyed) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (loggedIn) {
        if (!isWeekly) {
            myIntent.putExtra("DATA", false);
            if (isDestroyed) {
                dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", true);
            } else {
                dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", false);
            }
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 11133,
                    myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    getFuture10AMData(2), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent);
        } else {
            myIntent.putExtra("DATA", false);
            if (isDestroyed) {
                dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", true);
            } else {
                dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", false);
            }
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 11133,
                    myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    getFuture10AMData(8), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent);
        }

    } else {
        myIntent.putExtra("DATA", false);
        if (isDestroyed) {
            dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", true);
        } else {
            dataIntent.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", false);
        }
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 11133, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, getFuture10AMData(1),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

}

private static long getFuture10AMData(int count) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Date today = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, count);
    // Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();

}
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean isDataReminder = intent.getBooleanExtra("DATA", false);
    boolean isDestroyed = intent.getBooleanExtra("ISDESTROYED", false);

    Intent dataNotificationService = new Intent(context,
            DataNotificationService.class);
    Intent notificationService = new Intent(context,
            NotificationService.class);
    if (isDataReminder) {
        dataNotificationService.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", isDestroyed);
        context.startService(dataNotificationService);
    } else {
        notificationService.putExtra("ISDESTROYED", isDestroyed);
        context.startService(notificationService);
    }

}
```

Service code----

```
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Prefs.getInstance().loadPrefs(getApplicationContext());
        Log.i("MBB APP", "Data Service called");
        boolean isDestroyed = intent.getBooleanExtra("ISDESTROYED", false);
        System.out.println("Data Service Booleans"
                + BaseActivity.dataAlreadyBackrogund + ","
                + BaseActivity.isDataPutToBackground
                + "  ISDestroyed boolean " + isDestroyed);
        try {
            if (BaseActivity.dataAlreadyBackrogund
                    && BaseActivity.isDataPutToBackground) {
                if (BaseActivity.isDataPutToBackground
                        && Prefs.getInstance().isLoggedIn) {
                    generateDataNotification(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "You have created "
                                    + Prefs.getInstance().noOfQuotes
                                    + " and saved "
                                    + Prefs.getInstance().noOfLeads
                                    + " using MBB"
                                    + "\n"
                                    + "You last Quoted with MBB on "
                                    + Prefs.getInstance().lastQuoteTimeStamp
                                    + "\n"
                                    + "You last saved Lead with MBB on "
                                    + Prefs.getInstance().lastLeadTimeStamp
                                    + "\n"
                                    + "Add to your book of business now");

                }
            } else {
                BaseActivity.dataAlreadyBackrogund = true;
                // Prefs.getInstance().savePrefs(getApplicationContext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MBB Service Exception", e.toString());

        }
    }
```

Logs ----

```
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.test..DataNotificationService@41d2d050 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2571)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-03 15:42:04.008: E/AndroidRuntime(10701):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is that the full log cat?

Comment: y, please extend the log cat...

Comment: Its almost the full log.

Comment: It is unclear where the error accures from this log...

Comment: where is onDestroy code ?can u post?can u point out line where it is crashing?

Comment: Updated the code... Its crashing when onDestroy is called in BaseActivity in the onStart method of the service

Comment: post ur full **logcat**

Comment: Did u use the unbindreciever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you put your code to another place.
From the official site:

Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.
:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the issue is that this code is occurring in `onDestroy()` which is usually reserved for UI cleanup, so the `Context` object is not going to be reliable. Try moving this code to `onStop()` instead.

For reference, this is the Android Activity lifecycle.
[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should call `super.onDestroy()` when you are done with your local cleanup:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (!isResume) {
        isResume = false;
        isPutToBackground = true;
        isDataPutToBackground = true;
        setNotification(_instance, true);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```